# Using Jmeter how extracted values can be inserted to different columns of a database table

Tags: jdbc, jmeter, beanshell

Using JMeter-Bean shell sampler, I have extracted and split(with ',' delimiter) dynamic string. Currently I got stuck how this split values can be inserted to different columns of a database table.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code snippet which prints all the values after split. After splitting the string, each value will store into an array. You can retrieve by specifying the array position.

You can use the variable name e.g. aftersplit[0], aftersplit[1], and so on in the insert query.

```
String mystring = "here is my, dynamic, random, and unique string";
String[] aftersplit = mystring.split(",");

System.out.println(aftersplit[0]);
System.out.println(aftersplit[1]);
System.out.println(aftersplit[2]);

//To print all the values after splitting

for (int i=0; i < aftersplit.length; i++){
 System.out.println(aftersplit[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend the following approach: store your dynamic values into [JMeter Variables](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) having number postfix, example code:

```
String source = "foo,bar,baz";

int counter = 1;

for (String token : source.split(",")) {
    vars.put("token_" + counter, token);
    counter++;
}
```

It produces the following JMeter Variables:

```
token_1=foo
token_2=bar
token_3=baz
```

Then add [ForEach Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#ForEach_Controller) to iterate the generated variables and [JDBC Request sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_Request) as a child of the ForEach Controller to insert them into the database. See [The Real Secret to Building a Database Test Plan With JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/real-secret-building-database-test-plan-jmeter) to learn how to establish database connection and execute arbitrary SQL queries using JMeter